# Backbone Model Binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Trying to setup a successful binding on a model.

Binding works when adding/removing/updating values to the model. But once I recreate the model, binding stops working. I need to create new model so it gets new id/cid when saved to Collection.

I tried `this.model.clear()` but that doesn't assign new id/cid to the model.

Hope it makes sense. Thank you!

```
app.View = Backbone.View.extend({    

    initialize: function() {
      this.model = new app.Model();
      this.listenTo(this.model,'change', this.semaphore);
    },

    start: function(value) {
      // Create new model unless running app first time
      if( this.model.attributes.title != null ) this.model = new app.Model();
      this.model.set({title: value});
    },

    semaphore: function() {
      // Doesn't get call when new model gets reassigned
      // Do stuff...
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not move all your binding calls to a separate method? Then call that method from `initialize` and call it again when you assign a new model. This "other method" would presumably also handle unbinding listeners from the old model to help prevent memory leaks and such.

Comment: That's an idea. Can you give me an example?
Cause the unbinding should happen before the reassignment and the rebinding right after.. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Nothing fancy but it works:

```
initialize: function() {
   // Leave it blank
},

// New element gets created within the view
start: function(value) {
  // Creates new model
  this.model = new app.Word();
  // Binds it to a function
  this.listenTo(this.model,'change', this.semaphore);
  // Set value(s) so binding function reacts to it      
  this.model.set({title: value});
},
```